How do I track a contour from my previous image?
So I have a video of bacterial cells moving around which I converted to frames. Now I want to find the instantaneous velocity of each bacterial cells. For this I am interested in finding by how much a bacterial cell moved but I dont know how to tell my programme to accurately identify that this specific bacteria moved. For example, lets say I have only two images. For each image, I have the COM coordinate of each bacteria. Now how do I relate this data. How do I ask my programme to accurately identify that this much was the change in COM for this specific bacteria. I have attached the two images for reference.


A method I thought was to give each contour a unique id and associate the features of that contour with that unique id. For example its major axis and minor axis length. Then this way I can relate the contour's initial and final COM. But this idea assumes that all the bacterial cells are unique and that my code to accurately and precisely identifies contours of each bacterial cells which it does not. I have attached my code for finding contours of each bacterial cells too just in case you are interested. Can someone suggest some better ideas? Thankyou so much.
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
import math

def gaussian_filter_multiscale_retinex(image: NDArray, sigmas: list[float], weights: list[float]) -> NDArray:
    img32 = image.astype('float32') / 255

    img32_log = cv.log(img32 + 1)

    msr = np.zeros(image.shape, np.float32)
    for sigma, weight in zip(sigmas, weights):

        blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img32, ksize=(0, 0), sigmaX=sigma)
        blur_log = cv.log(blur + 1)
        ssr = cv.subtract(img32_log, blur_log)
        ssr = cv.multiply(ssr, weight)

        msr = cv.add(msr, ssr)

    msr = cv.divide(msr, sum(weights))

    msr = cv.normalize(msr, None, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX, cv.CV_8U)
    return msr
def calculate_ellipse_area(ellipse):

    (cx, cy), (a, b), angle = ellipse
    semi_major_axis = a / 2
    semi_minor_axis = b / 2
    area = math.pi * semi_major_axis * semi_minor_axis
    return area,angle

def process_image(img, size_threshold):
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    rtnx = gaussian_filter_multiscale_retinex(gray, sigmas=[15, 55, 185], weights=[10, 5, 1])
    thresholded = cv.adaptiveThreshold(rtnx, 255, adaptiveMethod=cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                                        thresholdType=cv.THRESH_BINARY, blockSize=7, C=-7)
    nb_components, output, stats, _ = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresholded, connectivity=8)
    sizes = stats[1:, -1]
    new_img = np.zeros_like(thresholded)
    for i in range(0, nb_components - 1):
        if sizes[i] >= size_threshold:
            new_img[output == i + 1] = 255
    connected_components = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(new_img)
    (numLabels, labels, stats, centroids) = connected_components

    result_image = np.ones_like(img) * 255
    for i in range(1, numLabels):
        componentMask = (labels == i).astype('uint8')
        contours, _ = cv.findContours(componentMask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        if len(contours) > 0:
            cnt = contours[0]
            if len(cnt) >= 5:
                ellipse = cv.fitEllipse(cnt)
                area, angle = calculate_ellipse_area(ellipse)
                if area < 250:
                    cv.ellipse(result_image, ellipse, (0, 0, 0), 1)  # Draw black contours on white background
    return result_image
img1path = "/Users/yahya2/Desktop/1.png"
img = cv.imread(img1path)
size_threshold = 16
result_image = process_image(img, size_threshold)

cv.imshow('Contours', result_image)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()


Why not look for nearby, similar looking ones?

@oskarThe cells are almost identical, moving in same direction. Wont that lead to a lot of error?

I mean, they won't move from the left edge to the right edge in one frame (I hope). So it makes sense to consider the distance, they have traveled in one frame

May be try use Optical Flow? https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html

the author asked related questions in the past (very similar pictures). for context, visit the author's profile and browse older questions.

As suggested by @Alex Alex, Optical Flow is certainly the way to go.
The idea of the code bellow is to compute Optical Flow between the two images, then to take a few points of the contours of each cell and average the flow of these point to obtain a "cell flow". This flow is then displayed.
The result for your two images:

def get_contour_center(contour):
    m = cv.moments(contour)
    if m['m00'] != 0: 
        cx = int(m['m10']/m['m00'])
        cy = int(m['m01']/m['m00'])

        return cx, cy
    return None

def draw_arrow(img, x, y, fx, fy, arrow_length_coef=2):
    lines = np.int32(np.array([x, y, x + fx*arrow_length_coef, y + fy*arrow_length_coef]) ).reshape(-1, 2, 2)

    cv.line(img, (int(x),int(y)),(int(x + fx*arrow_length_coef), int(y + fy*arrow_length_coef)), (0, 255, 0),1) 
    # cv.polylines(img, lines, 0, (0, 255, 0))
    cv.circle(img, (x, y), 1, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    return img

def draw_cell_movement(img1, img2, filtered_contour_list, result_image):

    img1_gray = cv.cvtColor(img1, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    img2_gray = cv.cvtColor(img2, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 

    # Calculates dense optical flow by Farneback method 
    flow = cv.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(img1_gray, img2_gray, None, 0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0) 

    for cnt in filtered_contour_list:
        
        # Take a few point of cell contour (here six at most)
        ids = np.random.randint(0,cnt.shape[0],min(cnt.shape[0],6))
        cell_flow = np.zeros(2)
        for id in ids:
            x, y = cnt[id,:,:][0]
            fx, fy = flow[y, x].T

            cell_flow += flow[y, x]
        cell_flow /= len(ids)

        # find cell center and draw arrow direction
        center = get_contour_center(cnt)
        if center:
            cx, cy = center
            result_image = draw_arrow(result_image, x, y, fx, fy)
    return result_image

img1 = cv.imread("/mnt/d/wsl/experiments/trasj/bac1.jpg")
img2 = cv.imread("/mnt/d/wsl/experiments/trasj/bac2.jpg")
result_image, filtered_contour_list = process_image(img1, size_threshold)
result_image = draw_cell_movement(img1, img2, filtered_contour_list, result_image)

plt.imshow(result_image)
plt.show()

Note that given that your contours are actually ellipses there is a smarter way to sample the contours points and to find the center.
Also I have modified your process_image() so that it also return the contours you used to draw your ellipses.
